# Trouble with vertical white space when using multicol

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

I am trying to reduce the space between a subheading and a two column `multicol`. I have tried to change the margins on both the mutlticol and the heading, however it has lead me to no avail.

This is what I have written for the multicol / header (the data is just dummy data):

[image: tex]

This is the output from this:

[image: whitespace]

(Note: the Language section is as expected. That is what I am going for.)

This amount of white-space is too much, and no already answered questions that I could find seems to be addressing this. I believe I did read an answer saying that multicol may not be the correct solution, but I would assume there has to be a way to squish that space to make it more consistent.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Also, if you do provide code, please provide it as text and not as a picture. I'm not going to painfully type in your code, let me copy it from here.

Comment: What about `\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}` or whatever you need? Hard to give better advice since you are using custom commands and aren't providing us with their definitions....

Answer (score 1):

You could try using minipages instead of multicols. That way, you can also vary a bit with the horizontal alignment of the text by adding \centering and changing the textwidth.

```
Test
\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item An item;
\item Another item;
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Yet another;
\item And another.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

Edit: It does add the downside of having to split the list manually, but as far as I can see when testing it the problem of the vertical gap is gone

Comment: Why the figure environment?  \noindent is all you need.

Comment: It has become a bit of a habit. I use minipages a lot, almost always for figures and tables. You're right, I will change it